# File Permissions Issues in Ubuntu 18.04 ngnix and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, file-permissions, ubuntu-18.04

I am having a very strange issue. I have a DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04 with nginx as the web server and php fpm 7.2. I have a WooCommerce site but the wc_logs folder is not writable.

I have verified that it is set to 775 and the owner and group are the same as all the other directories. When I run `stat wc_logs` I get `Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/USERNAME)   Gid: (   33/www-data)`. This is the same as other directories that seem to be writable.

I have about 30 other sites on this vps, some WooCommerce some just WordPress, but only one other site has issues. The issue on that site is updating plugins (for what I believe to also be permission issues). We can stick to why wc_logs is not writable by WordPress for this questions.

I am somewhat new to server configuration and am learning as I go so please forgive improper language or knowledge!

Thanks guys!

Comment: What user are your webservices / wordpress running under? Is said user owner of the folder in question, or at least member of the owner group? If not it will fall under "others" which has r-x, thus no write-permission.

Comment: They should be running under nicktaylor/www-data. nicktaylor is in the www-data group. I mean the other directories right next to the wc_logs directory are writable and they have the exact same user and group.

Comment: Could you show an output of ls -la of the folder in which wc_logs resides, and also a ls -la of the wc_logs folder itself?

Comment: Sure thing. uploads is where wc_logs resides:
`drwxrwxr-x  8 nicktaylor www-data 73728 Sep  5 09:04 uploads/`

And wc_logs itself: `drwxrwxr-x 2 nicktaylor www-data 4096 Sep  4 09:31 wc_logs//`